# Left e Translate

Tags: html5, css3

Recentemente vi que alguns programadores estão usando `left` e `translate`, ao invés de `left` e `margin`.

Exemplo abaixo

```css
.container{
width 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
height:300px;
}
.bloco1{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%, 50%);

}
.bloco2{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
top:35%;
left:50%;
margin-left:-5%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="bloco1"></div>
<div class="bloco2"></div>
</div>
```

Qual a diferença entre os dois, qual o melhor e mais eficiente?

Comment: Como assim? Depende do escopo de como vc vai usar.... falando só assim é difícil te dar uma resposta. No seu bloco2 por exemplo para centralizar na horizontal, basta remover o `position:absolute` e colocar `margin: auto` que ele fica no centro.... Explique melhor o que vc precisa.

Comment: quero saber qual a melhor maneira de posicionar um elemento no centro responsivamente

Comment: Nesse caso transform:translate pode ser melhor pq facilita pra centralizar tanto na vertical quanto horizontal, independente da largura e altura dos elementos. Usando margin vc pode precisar de "números perfeitos" para achar as distancias ideais e mesmo assim pode não ser 100% responsivo dependo da tela. Mas cada caso é um caso

Answer (score 0):

O **[translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate)** é um método **[transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function)** usado para mover elementos.

Ele aceita dois valores que representam os eixos `X` (horizontal) e o `Y` (vertical).

A diferença entre `translate` e `margin-left` é apenas conceitual. Enquanto um move o elemento, ou outro apenas aplica uma margem.

A vantagem do `translate` sobre o `margin` é que ele é bem mais eficiente e flexível quando se quer posicionar ou mover um elemento.

Por exemplo:

Com `translate` eu consigo centralizar uma `div` independentemente da sua largura:

```css
div{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
   foo
</div>
```

Já com `margin-left`, para ter o mesmo resultado, eu fico "preso" à largura da `div`, porque para centralizar eu preciso recuar a metade da largura (`-50px`):

```css
div{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -50px;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
   foo
</div>
```

Ou seja, com `translate`, não importa a largura do elemento que ele ficará sempre centralizado, enquanto que com `margin-left`, eu preciso saber a largura do elemento e colocar um valor fixo (a metade).

Comment: Valeu Bro, obrigado ai. Então o melhor é usar o translate não é, pratico, rapido e eficiente?

Comment: Em certos casos sim.